# prevent default context menu in angular7

Tags: angular, datatable, contextmenu

In my Angular project I use an angular `data-table` and created a context menu. But when clicking on it the default right click option also appears with the created  context menu. How can I prevent a default right click action in Angular?

Answer (score 3):

Use `event.preventDefault()` :

**HTML**

```
<div (contextmenu)="foo($event)">
  [...]
</div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
foo($event: MouseEvent) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  /* INSERT CODE HERE */
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me,the context menu completely disappears.Can I have pure typescript code. I tried event.stopPropagation() but still not working.

Comment: I found a temporary solution setting                                                                      <body class="app" oncontextmenu="return false">             in index.html,Anyway thanks for helping:)